# sending file with other post data using advanced rest client?

Tags: laravel, advanced-rest-client

I've been trying to send file with other post data which is mentioned in picture below also whenever i execute it, i only receive file but not other post data, it says **"null"** :-

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBRww.png)

Do i have to use **multipart/form-data** for file and other details for **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** ?

In my laravel project , api is set to POST

http://localhost/myproject/api/response

```
Route::post('response',function(Request $r){
    $url = '';
    if($r->hasFile('file')){
        $file = $r->file('file');
        $filename = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = public_path().'/uploads/videos/';
        if(!empty($file->move($path, $filename)))
        {
            $url = asset('/uploads/videos/'.$filename);
        }else {
            $url = '';
        }
    }else {
        $url = '';
    }
    $query = Table::create([
        'response_status'    => $r->get('status'),
        'response_video_url' => $url,
        'v_id'         => $r->get('vid'),
        'b_id'     => $r->get('bid')
    ])->id;
    if($query){
        $data = [
            'message' => 'Response is incorrect'
        ];
    }else{
        $data = [
            'message'            => 'Response received.',
            'response_id'        => $query,
            'response_video_url' => $url
        ];
    }
    return response()->json($data);
});
```

Comment: what you want to do ? `dd` is used to echo and die it will exit on first line `dd($r->file('file'));  `

Comment: I know that that was an example actually, i'm saving this into db with query.

Comment: show your code of saving data in db

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681530/guzzle-laravel-how-to-make-request-with-x-www-form-url-encoded  see it may be it will help you

Comment: I Updated My Code

Answer (score 1):

I tried and i got the answer,
there is no need to mention **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** while uploading file with data **"multipart/form-data"** is enough to do the job, by clicking on ADD TEXT PART and leave the **Content Type (optional)** field empty..

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRGXp.png)

Thank you so much for help.